# Out of bounds exception for list view with multiple View types

Tags: android, listview

I always get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` after a few messages, whether they are being received or being loaded from database.
It always happens at the same index

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2

The entire trace is of the framework and I cannot understand where I'm going wrong.

Part of my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
    Log.v(TAG, ".chatCreated createdLocally:" + createdLocally);
    chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Message Received : " + message);
            Log.v(TAG, "From:" + message.getFrom());
            Log.v(TAG, "Type : " + message.getType());
            Log.v(TAG, "Boody:" + message.getBody());
            final Message msg = message;
            Date date = new Date();
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                final SqlMessage sqlMessage = new SqlMessage();
                sqlMessage.body = message.getBody();
                sqlMessage.time = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                sqlMessage.type = SqlMessage.TYPE_RECEIVER;
                MessagesDao.storeNew(mDatabase, sqlMessage);
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(() -> {
                    mChatMessageAdapter.add(sqlMessage);
                    Log.v(TAG, "msg inside handler : " + msg);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

private class ChatMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SqlMessage> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ChatMessageAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, -1);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getview pos:" + position);
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            int resource;
            switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                case SqlMessage.TYPE_SENDER:
                    resource = R.layout.list_item_sender_msg;
                    break;
                case SqlMessage.TYPE_RECEIVER:
                    resource = R.layout.list_item_receiver_msg;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        SqlMessage message = getItem(position);

        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US).format(message.time);
        Spannable messageSpannable = new SpannableString(message.body + '\n' + time);
        messageSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), messageSpannable.length() - time.length(),
                messageSpannable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        messageSpannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), messageSpannable.length() - time.length(),
                messageSpannable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(messageSpannable);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

trace:

```
05-21 10:14:32.561    9432-9432/genie.com.yourgenieapp E/AndroidRuntimeï¹• FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: genie.com.yourgenieapp, PID: 9432
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6563)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1632)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2102)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1859)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: because you are accessing wrong index in your list. Could be getViewTypeCount() as you have hard coded count.

Comment: What are the possible values of `type` for your `SqlMessage` class?

Comment: How come I did not find this answer when I looked on SO but now everyone seems to know the answer.
Plus I have -1 . The down voter cares to comment?

Comment: But thanks @Shahzeb and Mike M. , that was my problem

Comment: @vedant1811 Anytime :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out my `public int getItemViewType(int position)` was to blame. I had changed code elsewhere and was returning indices `1` and `2` rather than `0` and `1`.

It may be a minor mistake but the incorrect error reporting made this a major headache. Error should have been properly thrown when `getItemViewType(int position)` returned a number greater than `getViewTypeCount() - 1`

Thanks to **TacticalJoke** (IRC nick on `#android-dev`) for fixing this error.